# R - converting data in a more efficient way

Tags: r

everyone.My task is to join three datasets with 8 columns into one with R and then:
1) from column 1-5 - all  questions should be converted to NA
2) from column 1-5 - all string and non-numeric answers should be converted to -2.

The problem is that when I am reading the files, it is automatically converting everything to characters and when I apply the as.numeric function, it is converting all not-possible-to-be-converted-into-numeric characters to NA, thus converting the strings into NA alongside  making it impossible to track what is what later on.

For example, I have:

```
 Answer.1      Answer.2      Answer.3
1 don't know   <Unanswered>    5
2 4             a-1           <Unanswered>
3 1             5              4
```

What I want as an output is this:

```
Answer.1      Answer.2      Answer.3
1 -2        NA              5
2  4        -2              NA
3  1         5              4
```

I did manage to find solution by typing this ugly code:

```
copy <- bind_rows(group1, group2, group3)


copy[, 1:5] <- gsub("<Unanswered>", "5000", copy[,1:6])

copy$Answer.1 <- gsub("<Unanswered>", "5000", copy$Answer.1)
copy$Answer.2 <- gsub("<Unanswered>", "5000", copy$Answer.2)
copy$Answer.3 <- gsub("<Unanswered>", "5000", copy$Answer.3)
copy$Answer.4 <- gsub("<Unanswered>", "5000", copy$Answer.4)
copy$Answer.5 <- gsub("<Unanswered>", "5000", copy$Answer.5)

copy$Answer.1 <- as.numeric(copy$Answer.1)
copy$Answer.2 <- as.numeric(copy$Answer.2)
copy$Answer.3 <- as.numeric(copy$Answer.3)
copy$Answer.4 <- as.numeric(copy$Answer.4)
copy$Answer.5 <- as.numeric(copy$Answer.5)

copy[is.na(copy)] <- -2
copy[copy == 5000] <- NA
```

However, I am curious if there is a more efficient way to do this. Please bear in mind our assignment does not allow us to use any other packages than dplyr and tidyr.

Comment: I didn't quite get question completely, but if you are using read.csv() to read your files, you can use the "na.strings" parameter to convert the strings that you want to be read as NA. For example, read.csv("datafile.csv", na.strings = c("<Unanswered>"))

Comment: To avoid reading everything as strings automatically, you can use stringsAsFactors = FALSE inside the read.csv() function.

Comment: I tried both things but it is still not working.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but the above two are not solutions to the final output you want. They are intermediate steps that will help you towards your final output. What is not working? What is the error(if any) that you are getting? What is the code that you are using to read the files?

Comment: I've managed to do it now! Actually, I simply used this:

Comment: copy <- bind_rows(group1, group2, group3)
    copy[copy == "<Unanswered>"] <- -2
    copy[, 1:5] <- mutate_each(copy[, 1:5], funs(as.numeric))

Comment: Now, an easier thing, I also should turn all numbers above 24 to -2 as well, but again, only in columns 1-5. Do you have any suggestions for that? If I write:

copy[copy > 24] <- -2 , this affects my whole table. How can I subset with this sort of function?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the question asked in the comments.

```
n <- cbind(apply(n[,1:5], 2 , function(x) ifelse(x > 24, -2, x)), n[,6]) 
#Output
      n1 n2 n3 n4 n5   
 [1,]  2  2  2  2  2  2
 [2,]  4  4  4  4  4  4
 [3,]  6  6  6  6  6  6
 [4,]  8  8  8  8  8  8
 [5,] 10 10 10 10 10 10
 [6,] 12 12 12 12 12 12
 [7,] 14 14 14 14 14 14
 [8,] 16 16 16 16 16 16
 [9,] 18 18 18 18 18 18
[10,] 20 20 20 20 20 20
[11,] 22 22 22 22 22 22
[12,] 24 24 24 24 24 24
[13,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 26
[14,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 28
[15,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 30
[16,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 32
[17,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 34
[18,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 36
[19,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 38
[20,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 40
[21,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 42
[22,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 44
[23,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 46
[24,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 48
[25,] -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 50
```

Here n is the name of the dataset and I am assuming there are only 6 columns. You can change it according to your dataset.

A simpler solution would be:

```
n[1:5] <- lapply(n[1:5], function(x) ifelse(x > 24, -2, x))
```

Comment: Do you suggest to create a function in advance? I do not get what is function doing there, thanks! :)

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation for apply/lapply/sapply and understanding how that works. You can use ?apply in you console for the documentation.

Comment: @Assen - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I am a complete noob in R and I do not fully understand how to use this function() in lapply. Could you please give me a concrete example. Thank you!

Comment: These links should help: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family   https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/